# Job Scheduler running two times within a second when unlocking phone

Tags: java, android, android-jobscheduler

I am trying to send my location values periodically from android phone to a server application and i set the time period to 1 minute. When i started the service the jobservice works fine but after a few minutes when i am unlocking my phone, Jobservice send two data within 1 second. Is there anything wrong in my code

**MainActivity.java**

```
    JobScheduler jobScheduler=
 (JobScheduler)getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);

ComponentName jobService = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), 
ServiceClass.class.getName());
    JobInfo.Builder jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(MY_JOB, jobService);
    PersistableBundle bundle = new PersistableBundle();
    jobInfo.setPeriodic(period*60*1000);
 int jobId = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo.build());
    if(jobId>0){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully scheduled job 
    ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        btstartservice.setEnabled(false);
        btstopservice.setEnabled(true);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Faild to start service 
  ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**ServiceClass.java**

```
   public class ServiceClass extends JobService implements LocationListener{
      public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
         getLocation();
         return false;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Service 
          Stopped",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          return false;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the JobInfo code, [MIN_PERIOD_MILLIS](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/job/JobInfo.java#110) is set to 15 minutes. Anything that is set below this period will actually use 15 minutes.

See this [comment](http://androidxref.com/8.0.0_r4/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/job/JobInfo.java#122) in the code too:

> Query the minimum interval allowed for periodic scheduled jobs. 
>   Attempting to declare a smaller period that this when scheduling a job
>   will result in a job that is still periodic, but will run with this
>   effective period.

A recurring task with your interval will need some other service, possibly the Alarm Manager will work for you.

Comment: I have tried Alarm Manager first but it did not perform well. I also read about the difference between Alarm Manager and JobScheduler and I think [JobScheduler](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/choosing-the-right-background-scheduler-in-android/)  is efficient for periodic task.

Comment: I agree, if your periodic task does not need an interval of <15 minutes, JobScheduler has many advantages. I'd be curious on the issues you see with Alarm Manager, but a different thread would probably be more appropriate.

Comment: See this thread too for Job intervals that <15 minutes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39641278/job-scheduler-in-android-n-with-less-then-15-minutes-interval

Comment: I have tried setting the periodic interval to 20 minutes, but the same thing happening when i unlock my phone.