# Android JobScheduler is not worked

Tags: android, job-scheduling

I implement job scheduler in my Android app. For this i apply framework JobScheduler.

```
JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler)getSystemService(JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
    ComponentName jobService =
            new ComponentName(getBaseContext(), ServiceAppControl.class);
    JobInfo jobInfo =
            new JobInfo.Builder(MYJOBID, jobService)
                    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
                    .setPeriodic(100)
                    .setPersisted(true)
                    .build();
    jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
```

manifest.xml

```
<service
        android:name=".services.ServiceAppControl"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true"/>
```

ServiceAppControl

```
public class ServiceAppControl extends JobService {

@Override
public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters params) {
    Log.d("Control", "onStartJob");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters params) {
    return false;
}
}
```

I did everything right? Logging is performed only once in about 10 minutes.

---EDIT---

I found such entries in the logcat. Could this mean something?

10-12 13:40:48.324 24072-24072/ru.test.testjobscheduler W/JobInfo: Specified interval for 1001 is +1s0ms. Clamped to +15m0s0ms
10-12 13:40:48.324 24072-24072/ru.test.testjobscheduler W/JobInfo: Specified flex for 1001 is +1s0ms. Clamped to +5m0s0ms

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct network connection available for the job to run? `setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)` and from documentation: "Bear in mind that calling this function defines network as a strict requirement for your job. If the network requested is not available your job will never run.". Try removing this setting and check if the job is run as expected.

Comment: yes, wi-fi is used as a connection. I tried without this line of code, but in this case it does not work either.

Comment: and no related logcat errors/warnings?

Comment: No, in logcat record error or warning not exist.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38774104/3635454

Answer (score 2):

JobScheduler works with a minimum periodic of 15 mins
change to `.setPeriodic(15 * 60 * 1000)`